# Is hoping that man can bring dinosaurs back to life kufr?

Tags: shirk, kufr

I read a line in an article which said that it might be possible to bring back dinosaurs from their DNA samples. It crossed my mind that only Allah can give life but I still kept reading hoping this was true because I got excited about the possibility of this. is what I did kufr? I hope you can give me a quick answer brothers and sisters

Comment: One day science may advance enough to clone even yourself. But only Allah can give life to the clones. Otherwise, it will be just a piece of meat with no consciousness.

Answer (score 2):

This does not constitute kufr in my opinion; kufr relates to matters of religious truth and whether or not you accept them, and you didn't deny the doctrine that only god gives life. Actually bringing back a dinosaur - or hoping that someone will - would no more be kufr than baking a cake.

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

What you are describing is, men bringing back dinosaurs **from their DNA.** But man still need the DNA. This isn't creating life. This would be using a process to use earth's resources to make something. That is not haram. So, no, you didn't commit kufr.